# github can't access folder after push

Tags: git, github, repository, push, pull

I was working in a folder and can push/pull with github quite well. But now I'm trying to wrap this folder with another one, and after pushing the new folder to github I can't get access to the subfolder(It exists in github, but can't be clicked). If someone pull it from github, it seems to be the right file size but with nothing in the subfolder.

The way I works:

1. I've been working in a folder and set up git there. I push this folder to github quite normally
2. Then I put this folder in an Aptana project folder, setting git from the project folder.
3. I set up git from an third folder, pulled from github, and deleted the content. I moved the content of Aptana project folder in, committed everything in the 'inner folder' (the one I was working on), and committed the Aptana project folder as well.
4. I made the push, and the subfolder seems to be empty in github

I was working on a different branch than "master" before, but seems like switching it to master does not help anyways.

Anybody knows what can I do with this? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: do you mean you moved the folder in a new folder? can you try to be more precise about the steps you followed cause it's difficult to understand what you did

Comment: You say it's empty on github, but is it empty on your local repo?

Comment: No, the subfolder (The one I was working on) is not empty in my local hard drive. Now it's like this in my computer: I have an Aptana folder which is a git repo, containing a subfolder which is also a git repo. The subfolder's content does not show up in github, if I push the Aptana folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you could manage this kind of transition is by:

- Considering your current repo (containing the `.git`) as the destination directory (like an Aptana folder)
- recreate the initial folder below the root repo directory
- move the content in that new folder (Git will recognize it is the same content, simply at a new place),
- add the new elements (like the Aptana project files)
- add everything (`git add -A`) and commit
- then push.

You can control the quality of that migration *before* pushing back to GitHub by cloning your local modified repo and see if that local clone has everything in it at its right (new) place.

Comment: Really it works! And all the history seems to be there. Thanks a lot man, you saved my day :D

Comment: What is the reason for this folder not being included in Github?

Comment: @JohnAndrews not sure (4 years later). I just suggested to recreate and add again the folder locally, before pushing to GitHub.

Comment: Jup, just did it and it solved my whole problem which I spent figuring out the whole weekend.. crazy!

Answer (score 1):

the same thing happened with me, after I pushed a react application.
I can view the folder but can't open it.

the thing I found more convenient is to delete the .git file (make sure you can display hidden files) in your application folder and create a new repo on git hub and push it again to that repo.after finishing delete that broken repo on git hub at the bottom of the repo setting page